# MUI my drawer submenu button list acting different when the same code is in a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I am trying to make a sidebar menu with an MUI drawer.
While I was making it I realized that opening the submenus stopped being animated when I put it in a function component for cleaner code.

My question is why is it different when I put the exact same code in a function component and when I put it directly into return? And what can I do to fix it?

This is my code in a code sandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/blissful-platform-p2crj4?file=/src/drawer.tsx

I am expecting the opening of the submenu to be animated when I put the button list in a function component and then put that component into render( HERE ).